# Any way to have NodeJS run locally with an Expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo

After some investigation, I realized I'd have to detach/eject my Expo app in order to use libraries such as [`nodejs-mobile-react-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mobile-react-native), a library that allows you to run (and ship) a NodeJS singleton thread with your client app.

So the problem here is that I can't use this library unless I detach - something that I've been doing my best thus far to avoid. It sees all references to this library as null and I've tried to even manually link it.

Is there perhaps another approach that someone knows of that allows you to run Node alongside React-Native, which is compatible with Expo?

Answer (score 0):

I have also used Expo in the past and because of similar limitations I switched over to Native Development using Swift but, in your situations what you can do is:

```
expo eject
```

in the application directory to detach your app from expo, once you have done this then you will have a plain react native app, then you can add any nodejs packages compatible with React Native.
Done!

Comment: Is it possible to reattach it to an expo project?